# How to get country list in a dropdown, need only county list and country code

Tags: flutter

[I need like this -> click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaijI.png)

How to get the country list in a dropdown in Flutter, I need only the county list and country code.

Answer (score 1):

This would give you a dropdown of country flag with their country code.
And you can find a list of country codes [here](https://www.iban.com/country-codes)

```
class dropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  

const dropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.locale,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Locale? locale;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getFlag(String code) {
      switch (code) {

    case 'es':
      return "";
    case 'de':
      return "";
    case 'fr':
      return "";
    case 'nl':
      return "";
    case 'zh':
      return "";
    default:
      return "";
  }
}

return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.language,
        color: kPrimaryColor,
      ),
      items: I10n.all.map((locale) {
        final flag = _getFlag(locale.languageCode);
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
            flag,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          )),
          value: locale,
          onTap: () {
            final provider =
                Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context, listen: false);
            provider.setLocale(locale);
          },
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (_) {},
    )));
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

in case you didn't find a solution yet, please refer to this [country_state_city](https://pub.dev/packages/country_state_city) package. It may be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_multi_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter). Stylize the CountryDropdown widget and enjoy :)